# Tangosol.coherence.xml loading at startup

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I have an application which is using coherence cache but at startup I am having this error:

> 2012-10-16 09:25:52,153 ERROR [resmanThreadExecutor-49]  getItem - 
>   (Wrapped: Failed to load operational configuration:
>   /tangosol-coherence.xml) java.io.IOException: The operational
>   configuration is missing: "/tangosol-coherence.xml",
>   loader=weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@122ccff
>   finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@2794e3
>   annotation:
>   ResponseManagerNew@ResponseManager-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
>           at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:288)
>           at com.tangosol.run.xml.XmlHelper.loadResourceInternal(XmlHelper.java:341)
>           at com.tangosol.run.xml.XmlHelper.loadResource(XmlHelper.java:251)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.application.console.Coherence.loadConfiguration(Coherence.CDB:19)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.application.console.Coherence.getServiceConfig(Coherence.CDB:13)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.application.console.Coherence.ensureRunningLogger(Coherence.CDB:15)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.application.console.Coherence.debugOutput(Coherence.CDB:1)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.Component._trace(Component.CDB:3)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeService.ensureRunningService(SafeService.CDB:37)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.safeService.SafeCacheService.ensureRunningCacheService(SafeCacheService.CDB:3)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache$CacheAction.run(SafeNamedCache.CDB:3)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:337)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.restartNamedCache(SafeNamedCache.CDB:8)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.ensureRunningNamedCache(SafeNamedCache.CDB:33)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.getRunningNamedCache(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
>           at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.get(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
>           at com.ttech.rbm.coherence.commoncache.blockage.CacheManager.getItem(CacheManager.java:36)
>           at com.tcell.resman.util.WebServiceUtil.callWriteResponseListWS(WebServiceUtil.java:152)
>           at com.tcell.resman.service.successmessage.impl.SuccessMessageFlow.processAccepted(SuccessMessageFlow.java:669)
>           at com.tcell.resman.service.successmessage.impl.SuccessMessageFlow.start(SuccessMessageFlow.java:281)
>           at com.tcell.resman.service.successmessage.impl.SuccessMessageFlow.execute(SuccessMessageFlow.java:78)
>           at com.tcell.resman.service.successmessage.impl.SuccessMessageFlow$$FastClassByCGLIB$$79bf8ebe.invoke()
>           at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:80)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Coherence jar is in my war file and I do not want to put it on weblogic startup classpath. The xml file is in the jar(coherence.jar). And the version of it is 3.7.1.5

Any ideas?

Comment: To start with figure out if your configuration xml file is in the correct location. After that it may be a issue with the server end of your cache. And then debug networking issues between your client and server.

Comment: The file is in the coherence.jar by default and the jar is in y classpath. About the network issue, it is not. It is running locally.